# How to add an image to MediaModel in Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to read and add an image programatically to MediaModel but not able to do.

Comment: What is your setup? Are you trying to implement a hot folder? What does debugging your code tell you? Please be more specific.

Comment: yes, i am trying to implement a hot folder like functionality. I wanted to convert my image file(which is available in data/mymedia folder) to other formats using mediaconversionstrategy and need to store in another folder(data/convertedmedia). but not able to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hot folders are based on Spring Integration project. You need some inbound-adapter to read image file, some service activator which converts image and outbound adapter that writes converter media to new folder.

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="readFiles" directory="/path/to/data/mymedia"
    filename-regex="^(.*)-(\d+)\.jpg">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" />
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:service-activator input-channel="readFiles" output-channel="convertedMedias" ref="someSpringBean"
    method="someMethod" />

<file:outbound-gateway request-channel="convertedMedias"
    directory="/path/to/data/convertedmedia" delete-source-files="true" />
```